# How to flip SVG coordinates?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a bar chart with the bars going **horizontal** created in an SVG. How would I flip the SVG to make the bar graph **vertical**?

I currently have `transform: 1, -1` in my CSS file but it isn't working. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below demonstrates one strategy you might use. In the SVG code one labeled graph is drawn 5 times:

[image]

1. *(untransformed original)*
2. - rotated 90 degrees
3. - rotated 90 degrees,
   - then flipped vertically *(and translated back into position)*
4. - rotated 90 degrees,
   - then flipped vertically *(and translated back into position)*,
   - then with all the labels flipped vertically again to restore the orientation of each *(with each label separately translated back into position)*
5. - rotated 90 degrees,
   - then flipped vertically *(and translated back into position)*,
   - then with all the labels flipped vertically again to restore the orientation of each *(with each label separately translated back into position)*,
   - then with the X label rotated 180 degrees

For each graph the outer `<g>` element is simply to position the five graphs next to each other and is irrelevant to understanding the graph-flip. In contrast, the inner `<g>` element has the transform that is critical for understanding the graph-flip.

```html
<svg width="600">
  <defs>
    <g id="graph" fill="none" stroke="black">
      <polyline points="20,0 20,90 110,90"/>
      <rect x="30" y="10" width="20" height="80"/>
      <rect x="70" y="40" width="20" height="50"/>
    </g>
    <g id="X_label">
      <text transform="translate(24,110)">X values</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Y_label">
      <text transform="rotate(270) translate(-86,12)">Y values</text>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0)">
    <g transform="">
      <use href="#graph"/>
      <use href="#X_label"/>
      <use href="#Y_label"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(120)">
    <g transform="rotate(90,60,60)">
      <use href="#graph"/>
      <use href="#X_label"/>
      <use href="#Y_label"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(240)">
    <g transform="rotate(90,60,60) scale(-1,1) translate(-120,0)">
      <use href="#graph"/>
      <use href="#X_label"/>
      <use href="#Y_label"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(360)">
    <g transform="rotate(90,60,60) scale(-1,1) translate(-120,0)">
      <use href="#graph"/>
      <use href="#X_label" transform="scale(-1,1) translate(-120,0)"/>
      <use href="#Y_label" transform="scale(-1,1) translate(-15,0)"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(480)">
    <g transform="rotate(90,60,60) scale(-1,1) translate(-120,0)">
      <use href="#graph"/>
      <use href="#X_label" transform="scale(-1,1) translate(-120,0) rotate(180,55,104)"/>
      <use href="#Y_label" transform="scale(-1,1) translate(-15,0)"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` and  `rotate()` to turn the SVG 90 degrees.

**Example**:

```
transform: rotate(90);
```

> **Note:** Since you didn't provide any code, after using `rotate()` you may also need to move the SVG back into place by using `translate()`.